# Overriding KStreams default serializer (ByteArraySerializer)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, ktable

I can't seem to override the serializer of a topic to `Serdes.String()`. I'm trying a simple use case of reading from a topic (stream), and writing to a KTable. What I have so far:

```
@Component
class Processor {
    @Autowired
    public void process(final StreamsBuilder builder) {
        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        builder.stream("input_topic", Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde))
                .filter((key, value) -> value.contains("ACTION"))
                .toTable(Materialized.as("output_table_materialized"))
                .toStream().to("output_table", Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde)); // EDIT: added this last line

    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key type (key type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

From what I gather, it understands the message is a `String` but it's using the default deserializer `ByteArraySerializer`. Where am I going wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and the solution was to specify the serdes on the `Materialized` instance, i.e. swapping

```
.toTable(Materialized.as("output_table_materialized"))
```

with

```
.toTable(Materialized.as("output_table_materialized").withKeySerde(stringSerde).withValueSerde(stringSerde))
```

Answer (score -1):

The Consumed.with would be a **De**serializer.

The error is on the Serializer, or the toTable call, which you may add `Produced.with` or modify your application properties to configure the defaults there

Comment: Thanks! Did some tests and arrived to the same conclusion. So I then tried re-converting the KTable back into a stream and writing to a topic there; however I get the same exception. I've edited the question if you don't mind looking at it again!

Comment: The KTable still needs types

Comment: not sure I understand...the toTable() doesn't seem to have Serde parameters. I even tried creating the `KTable<String, String>` variable first then converting it (though more out of desperation).
Also I don't see any mention of this in their documentation, been following:
https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-streams-convert-to-ktable/kstreams.html

Comment: The Materialized object takes a serde parameter as well https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#toTable-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized-  in that link, they do set `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_*_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG`... Do you not have that?